# Ti.StoreKit and Subscription

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, storekit

Does is anyone have a good process for monthly subscription using the Ti.Storekit? How do you store or handle data to find out if a users subscription has expired or is in good standings? I am new to the Ti.StoreKit any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StoreKit is free nowadays. Get it here: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/794?1042752485

Just follow the manual very closely, and you should be fine. If you have any specific questions ask it specifically.

Comment: How do you know when a feature has expired for a user and where is it stored?